# asio: is it safe to restart a async_read_some/async_write_some after cancel

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I have dificulty at finding a definite answer in the documentation.

I want to know if cancelling an async read or write operation and then later restarting operations can lead to corrupted data streams?

In detail for reading: If an async_read_some operation is running:

- cancel that operation through the stream descriptor
- wait for the handler to complete and process the result (either with a operation_aborted or bytes transfered).

Can I be sure that when I start a new async_read_some operation, that no data is lost? I.e. that when the handler returns operation_aborted error, that no data was read?

And likewise for async_write_some operation. When I cancel the operation, wait for the handler to finish, process the result (again I know that the return need not be operation_aborted), and then start writing remaining data, is it possible for the stream to duplicate data? I.e. can a cancel cause data to be written doubly when an writing is resumed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By itself, `cancel()` will not result in data loss or duplication in the stream.  Data loss or duplication will only occur in the application protocol if the application:

- initiates multiple read operations with the same underlying memory that succeed without processing the data which has been read
- initiates multiple write operations with the same underlying memory that succeed without changing the content of the memory which has already been written

Proper handling of the `error_code` and `bytes_transferred` passed to completion handlers will prevent this form of data loss or duplication.  If `bytes_transferred` is greater than `0`, then data has been either been read into the buffer from the socket or written to the socket from the buffer.  Be aware that if an operation has already been invoked or is queued for invocation in the near future, then the operation is no longer cancellable.  Consider the following scenario where `socket` has `42` bytes available to be read:

```cpp
assert(socket.available() == 42);
std::array<char, 32> buffer;
socket.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(buffer), ...); // op 1
socket.cancel();
socket.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(buffer), ...); // op 2
io_service.run();
```

If `op 1` is is successful and reads `32` bytes into `buffer`, then `10` bytes remain available to be read from `socket`.  `op 1`'s completion handler will be queued for invocation in the future with an `error_code` of success and `bytes_transferred` of `32`.  At this point, `socket.cancel()` has no effect on `op 1`.  Upon initiating `op 2`, the `10` remaining bytes are ready into the `buffer`, overwriting some of the un-processed data from `op 1`.  `op 2`'s completion handler will be queued for invocation in the future with an `error_code` of success and `bytes_transferred` of `10`.

---

For non-composed operations, such as [`socket.async_read_some()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/async_read_some.html):

- if an error occurred, such as cancellation, then `error_code` will not be `boost::system::errc::success` and `bytes_transferred` will always be `0`
- if an error did not occur, then `error_code` will be `boost::system::errc::success` and `bytes_transferred` will be greater than or equal to `0`

This behavior is documented for the [StreamSocketService](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/StreamSocketService.html)'s `async_receive()` and `async_send()` functions:

> If the operation completes successfully, the [handler] is invoked with the number of bytes transferred. Otherwise it is invoked with `0`.

On the other hand, with composed operations, such as [`boost::asio::async_read()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_read/overload1.html), the handler may be invoked with a non-success `error_code` and a non-zero `bytes_transferred`.  For example, if an `async_read()` operation is initiated and set to read 1024 bytes before completing, it may invoke `async_read_some()` multiple times. If 256 bytes are received and then the connection is closed, the `async_read()` handler will have a non-zero `error_code` and `bytes_transferred` will indicate that 256 bytes of the buffer are valid.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! What I really want to know is that after I call socket.cancel() can I restart operations again (e.g. async_read_some) without having lost information?

Comment: @Dirk I have updated the answer so that it is hopefully more specific to your question.  Data loss or duplication will only occur if the application reuses buffers and initiates operations without properly handling the results of previous operations.

Comment: Thank you very much - you answered my question perfectly!

Comment: @TannerSansbury I'm finding that when using async_write_some() that if I invoke cancel on the socket, bytes_transferred always returns 0 even if some bytes were successfully written (ultimately resulting in duplication).  How can I properly handle the results of the prior operation if it doesn't tell me how many of the bytes were actually written?